# Why my function (f(x)=x*2) doesn't returns anything?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I know that there are way simpler ways to calculate the square of a number and store it in an array, but for the sake of another problem. I need to understand why nothing happens in this code and its structure (is the return(a) necessary ?):

```
s=[1,2,3,4,5]


def square(x):
    return x*x
    def iterate(b):
        sol=[]
        for b in s:
            a=square(b)
            return(a)
            sol.append(a)
        print(sol)
```

The goal is to store the square in sol : sol = [1,4,9,16,25]. But the code runs without printing anything. What make the following code work and not the previous one ?

```
s=[1,2,3,4,5]

def square(x):
    return x*x
    
     
sol=[]
for b in s:
    a=square(b)
    sol.append(a)
print(sol)
```

(My problem involves curve fitting, and this structure doesnt fit my needs)

Comment: after the `return` statement the `iterate` function stops executing and the append never happens

Comment: You never call `iterate`.

Comment: It looks like you are defining a function inside a function. None of the functions are ever called.

Comment: Do not use `set` as a variable name. You are overwriting the built-in `set` function.

Comment: `iterate` never even gets *defined*, let alone called.

Comment: There are many problems with your code; I recommend spending more time with [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you define `iterate` within `square` but you never call `iterate`. It would be better to have `iterate` be a separate function that calls `square`:

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5]  # do not call your variable set - it is a Python keyword

def square(x):
    return x*x



def iterate(values):
    
    solution = []
    
    for value in values:
        value_squared = square(value)
        solution.append(value_squared)
    
    return solution
```

You could also do this without defining `iterate` using a list comprehension:

```
[square(value) for value in values]
```

Edit:

To answer your other questions, here is your code:

```
s=[1,2,3,4,5]


def square(x):
    return x*x
    def iterate(b):
        sol=[]
        for b in s:
            a=square(b)
            return(a)
            sol.append(a)
        print(sol)
```

In `square`, you never call `iterate` so this part of the code never runs.

If you add a call to `iterate` within `square`, you will end up in an infinite loop. This is because within `iterate` you call `square`, but you always iterate over your list `s`. This means that inside `iterate`, `square(b)` will always be `square(1)`.

Within `iterate` you use the global variable `s` but it would be better to restructure your code so that you take `s` as input.

If you are learning about inner functions, you could define `iterate` and within this define `square`:

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5]


def iterate(values):

    def _square(x):
        return x*x
    
    solution = []
    
    for value in values:
        value_squared = _square(value)
        solution.append(value_squared)
    
    return solution
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, as I am working with transcendental equations, I need to have iterate inside the square function because in my problem , "iterate" is the root solving procedure containing my fitting parameter.

Comment: I just saw you edited your answer to adress the other part of my question, that's what I want to do and I am thankful, when I run your code, I can't print ```solution``` . Do you know why ?

Comment: you should be able to do `solution = iterate(values)` and then `print(solution)`